# How to pass integer from one Activity to another?

Tags: android, integer, bundle

I would like to pass a new value for an integer from one Activity to another.
i.e.:

Activity B contains an

```
integer[] pics = { R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2, R.drawable.3}
```

I would like activity A to pass a new value to activity B:

```
integer[] pics = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c}
```

So that somehow through

```
private void startSwitcher() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

I can set this integer value.

I know this can be done somehow with a bundle, but I am not sure how I could get these values passed from Activity A to Activity B.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It's simple. On the sender side, use [`Intent.putExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

On the receiver side, use [`Intent.getIntExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

Their are two methods you can use to pass an integer. One is as shown below.

**A.class**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**B.class**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

The other method converts the integer to a string and uses the following code.

**A.class**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("StringVariableName", intValue + "");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

The code above will pass your integer value as a string to class B. On class B, get the string value and convert again as an integer as shown below.

**B.class**

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   String stringVariableName = extras.getString("StringVariableName");
   int intVariableName = Integer.parseInt(stringVariableName);
```

Answer (score 4):

In Activity A

```
private void startSwitcher() {
    int yourInt = 200;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    intent.putExtra("yourIntName", yourInt);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

in Activity B

```
int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("yourIntName", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sender Activity Side:

```
Intent passIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), "ActivityName".class);
passIntent.putExtra("value", integerValue);
startActivity(passIntent);
```

In Receiver Activity Side:

```
int receiveValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
```