# How to move to a new activity after the finishing the quiz?

Tags: android

I'm making an Android quiz app and it seems like it's all done except adding the questions but there is still a big error.
You see I've put that the random generater generates 4 questions. When I answer the fourth I would like that a new activity starts with the display of the score. Instead the app just doesn't respond. I'm really clueless.

Thank you!

```
package com.matej.hajdukkviz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Glavno extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

int score  = 0;

TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, countdown;
Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

ArrayList<Question> qsts = new ArrayList<Question>();
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<String> allAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

Random rng = new Random();
Question nextQuestion;

Question q1 = new Question(
        "Q1",

        "Correct answer - q1",
        "Wrong answer 1 - q1",
        "Wrong answer 2 - q1",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q1"
        );
Question q2 = new Question(
        "Q2?",

        "Correct answer - q2",
        "Wrong answer 1 - q2",
        "Wrong answer 2 - q2",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q2"
        );
Question q3 = new Question(
        "Q3?",

        "Correct answer - q3"
        "Wrong answer 1 - q3",
        "Wrong answer 2 - q3",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q3"
        );

Question q4 = new Question(
        "Q4?",

        "Correct answer - q4",
        "Wrong answer 1 - q4",
        "Wrong answer 2 - q4",
        "Wrong answer 3 - q4"
        );

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.pitanja);

// ADD THE QUESTIONS IN THE ArrayList qsts

    qsts.add(q1);           
    qsts.add(q2);
    qsts.add(q3);
    qsts.add(q4);

    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    countdown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);

    textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + score);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

    generateQuestion();

}

    public void generateQuestion(){

        while(true){

            int nxt = rng.nextInt(4);

            if (!generated.contains(nxt)){

                generated.add(nxt);

                nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);

                textView1.setText(nextQuestion.questionText);

                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer1);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer2);
                allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer3);

                Collections.shuffle(allAnswers);

                btn1.setText(allAnswers.get(0));
                btn2.setText(allAnswers.get(1));
                btn3.setText(allAnswers.get(2));
                btn4.setText(allAnswers.get(3));

                break;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

        if(buttonText.equals(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText)) { 

            textView2.setText("TOČNO!");
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + (score += 10));

            allAnswers.clear();
            generateQuestion();

            return;

        }else{

            textView2.setText("NETOČNO!");
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + (score -= 5));

            allAnswers.clear();
            generateQuestion();

            return; 
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Post your logcat so we can see where the error is. Also, where are you trying to start a new `Activity`?

Comment: there is no red text in the logcat it just doesnt respond... in this activity

Comment: Did you make sure the filter in your logcat is set to either "verbose" or "error"? Then step through and see what line causes it to stop responding. Also, I still don't see where you try to start a new `Activity`...

Comment: I don't know where to start it. You see that there is an OnClick method that tells what to do after the button is clicked. It sets a new question etc. But I would like that after the last question it takes me to a new activity..

Comment: Have you created this new `Activity` yet?

Comment: yes I did. It's empty,

Comment: just create the intent to the new activity and pass as parameter the score. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `generateQuestion()` your are looping while `true` (which is always the case) and then execute something only if the random question has not been shown. Of course this is an endless loop. If it is 4 questions, you can declare a global variable `counter` which you increase after each question. And instead of looping while `true` you say if `counter < 4` else `startNewIntent()` or similar with the code mentioned by codeMagic.

Comment: I've added a int counter that start with zero and increases with every click on a button.. I've added the startActivity(new Intent()) in the on click above these methods but it doesn't work..

Comment: did you start the Activity with the code mentioned by codeMagic? Do you have the second Activity called for example `NextActivityName`? If all yes, you have to post your updated code to see where the error is still.

Answer (score 0):

Put some stuff in your next `Activity`, make sure it is properly declared in the `manifest.xml`, create a layout for it then add this code after your last question is answered

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Glavno.this, NextActivityName.class);   // declare and initialize an Intent object
  startActivity(intent); // pass the Intent object to startActivity()
```

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

**Edit**

I see you already have accepted an answer but it sounds like its not working correctly. You aren't finishing so the code in your `onClick()` runs through. I'll edit what you have and post below. That should help.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

    if (counter == 4) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Glavno.this, Score.class));
        finish();   // Added this method call
    }

    else if(buttonText.equals(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText)) { // Changed this to else if

        counter++;

        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        textView2.setText("TOČNO!");
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + (score += 10));

        allAnswers.clear();
        generateQuestion();

        return;
    } 

    else{

        counter++;

        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        textView2.setText("NETOČNO!");
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textView3.setText("Rezultat: " + (score -= 5));

        allAnswers.clear();
        generateQuestion();

        return; 
    }

}
```

Comment: but how do I put this to start after the last questions is answered?

Comment: Create an `int` counter and add 1 each time they click the button. In `onClick()` check if counter equals question list size. If it does, start the next `Activity`