# Android pass increment value in intent between 2 activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, increment

I am passing a value in intent between 2 activities to dynamically change data..

I am getting the value passed from the end activity in my home activity in the onCreate like so -

```
// Get Variable From Home Activity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String curhole;
    curhole = extras.getString("hole");
    TextView holeno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.holeNumber);
    holeno.setText(String.valueOf("Hole " + curhole));
```

I have this onClick function in my home activity-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Get Variable From Home Activity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String curhole;
    curhole = extras.getString("hole");

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, end.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("hole",curhole);
    startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

Then in my end activity I grab that value and pass it back to the home activity -

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String curhole;
    curhole = extras.getString("hole");

    int incHole = Integer.parseInt(curhole);
    incHole++;
    String.valueOf(incHole);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, hole.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("hole",incHole);
    startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

When I click the home activity button to go to the end activity and back to home it says the value is null.. Any idea why? I am new to android so im sure my approach is probably whack.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some more code? Your problem is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you need to be getting the value in `onResume()` since it doesn't look like you are killing the `Home` Activity so `onCreate()` won't be called again.

You might want to make use of [`startActivityForResult()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243515/android-going-back-to-previous-activity-with-different-intent-value/18243541#18243541) in this type of case though, passing this way will work.

Also, `Intent` has a [`getIntExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)) method so I'm not sure you need to do all of the converting you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Share more. Why sending your `int` as `String`?

```
int incHole = Integer.parseInt(curhole);
incHole++;
//Should work as String or int
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, hole.class);
myIntent.putExtra("hole", incHole);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Let me know if helped. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7074143/6723193).

Comment: good question, I have had trouble with passing integers for some reason.. Although yes I need to do it passing a int value to save myself the leg work..

Answer (score 1):

I would pass through intent from home activity to end activity the variable but starting the activity as startActivityForResult(); then on home activity you should rewrite onActivityResult(); method to get back the variable from end activity.

Check [this tutorial of activity result](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) read the 2.3. Retrieving result data from a sub-activity

Answer (score 0):

When you press home then save bundle in saveInsatance() activity method.