# Send an image to another Activity - How change a resource to integer?

Tags: java, android

How can I send image res to another Activity - How change Resources to integer?
i create class to pass Image Resources to another activity:

public class MyImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnClickListener {

```
Context contxt;


public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setOnClickListener(this);
    this.contxt = context;
}


public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOnClickListener(this);
    this.contxt = context;
}


public MyImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOnClickListener(this);
    this.contxt = context;
}


@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {

    super.setOnClickListener(l);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int g = getResourse......................;(this is my peroblem)
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt("imagebitmap", g);
    Intent i = new Intent(contxt, zara.knauf.Img.class);
    i.putExtras(extras);
    contxt.startActivity(i);

}
}
```

Comment: You are mispelling resour**c**e to resour**s**e. I don't know if it helps, but it could generate issues in your code. Anyway, simlpy pass the **id** and retrieve the resour**c**e in the called Activity. DONE.

Comment: [Here you can find your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity) this is already solved hope this will help you.

Comment: @Ifran That's not passing a resource id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `g` to a `R.drawable` integer value. You don't need to call `getResources`.

You also don't need to create a `Bundle` object.

See [How to pass integer from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: sorry I create this calss :(MyImageView extends ImageView)

Comment: So...? That doesn't affect my answer