# Android pass variable to an intent

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent, android-activity

I have an class to start a new activity and I have a function inside that creates an intent. I need to pass MainActivity.class variable to that function.
Normally I do it like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

And I wan't to have something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, variable);
```

So I wan't to change activity to start basically. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass a class variable to the Intent?

Comment: Did you mean to pass variable from one activity to another?

Comment: According to you what is a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to use reflection to get the class name.

```
Class someActivity = Class.forName(getPackageName() + "MainActivity");
Intent intent = new Intent(context, someActivity);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Exactly. If I edit this code like this I can get what I wanted.

Comment: try {
                    Class someActivity = Class.forName(getPackageName() + ".MainActivity");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), someActivity);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Answer (score 0):

Search for your question before you post one, a lot of people have the same question as you.

I guess this is what you're looking for

[How to pass integer from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another)

Now instead of int use string which i guess that what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this one.

```
private void callActivity(Activity activity,Class<?> className)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, className);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Just pass activity from where you call another activity and the className which you need to call.

```
private void callActivity(Context context,Class<?> className)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, className);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```