# Passing spinner selection between activities

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have 4 activity with spinner inside every activity and this spinner include 3
string data (drop-down selection), when I pass from activity to another one I must pass this selected data inside spinner like if I have chosen data x from the list in the spinner and click in button the selected data must be in second activity spinner as x too.
I read several solutions without any solving. I hope to solve it here and this is my code for spinner and where to put the intent code

```
public class Page1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1); 

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter =   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.film_type,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            switch (position)
            {case 0:
                btn[0] = (FloatingTextButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
                btn[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            double thick = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
                            double width = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
                    }
                });
                break;
                case 1:
                    btn[0] = (FloatingTextButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
                    btn[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {

                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                //not a double
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save the position of selected data from spinner in a String variable,

```
int positionOfSelectedDataFromSpinner;

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       positionOfSelectedDataFromSpinner= position;
}
```

Then on `button` click send intent to Another activity with `putExtra`

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, activity2.class);

i.putExtra("position", positionOfSelectedDataFromSpinner);
startActivity(i);
```

get int from `getIntent` in another activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int positionToShowToSpinner = intent.getStringExtra("position");
```

then set the position to spinner

```
spinner.setSelection(positionToShowToSpinner);
```

I think this my solve your problem.

Comment: You can putExtra as integer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: thanks i did with  your code like this  :
           1-finalint[]positionOfSelectedDataFromSpinner = new int[1];
           2- positionOfSelectedDataFromSpinner[0] = position;           
        and get it in second activity                                                       
           3-  Intent    intent  = getIntent();
           int positionToShowToSpinner = intent.getIntExtra("position",0);            
      4- spinner.setSelection(positionToShowToSpinner);

Answer (score 1):

this is the most painless way i can think of:
make a new class or a static member of an existing class but the second solution makes the code less understandable.

```
public class SpinnerPosHolder{
    public static int poition;
}
```

then in all 4 of them:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
SpinnerPosHolder.position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

For using it:

```
spinner.setSelection(SpinnerPosHolder.position)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way

```
String selectedItem=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And that `String` you can pass using `Intent`

Comment: You can putExtra as integer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another