# How To Save And Display Int In Another Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have two activities, one is a clicker game (where you click a button and the textView displays an int (increasing per click). The other activity is where I display that int. I've tried many times of different ways of how to pass this data to the next activity, however nothing seemed to work. I assume that this could be because this int does not stay the same, and is constantly changing. Could anyone suggest what to do?

Clicker:

```
    Intent getNumber = new Intent(this, Shop.class);

    getNumber.putExtra("passedMoney", clicks);

    startActivity(getNumber);
```

Stats:

```
    Intent getNumber = getIntent();

    int clicks = getNumber.getIntExtra("passedMoney", 0);
```

**clicks** is the int, which is **0**.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass integer from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another) , make sure you have the data when you got to next activity

Comment: Hey put some code!

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show what you've tried, and explain exactly how it's failing. Passing data to another `Activity` is a pretty standard operation, and if you can't get any of the numerous examples available working, it's unlikely that users repeating them here will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I would've just did some research on it, however the int is does not have the same value (as when you click the button it changes)

Comment: @Thy_Great mean you are not sending the updated value

Comment: That could be it, but even when I click the button a couple of times and move on to the next activity to check my stats, I receive an int value of '0'

Comment: show code of `Clicker` activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data on click

```
startActivity(new Intent(vContext, OtherActivity.class).getIntExtra("number", itemData));
```

How to get data

```
int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("number", 0);
```