# How do I properly generate a random integer based on a specific start/end number in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create an Android app that takes in a user-inputted "from" number and "to" number (a range) and then generates a random integer from within that range. I'm using 2 EditTexts with the `number` `inputType` so that the user can input their unique values, and then I tried to work with the EditTexts in the corresponding Java files (both files are attached below).

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994407/9110418) and [here](https://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20824665/9110418).

However, Android Studio can build (compile) my app, but when I run the app in the emulator (which has been working before I added this logic), it refuses to even load the Activity and instead says "Unfortunately, [App] has stopped." I think it has something to do with leaving some parts of the "addTextChangedListener" code empty, but I don't know what exactly to put there (I took it from the examples I linked to above).

What on Earth am I doing wrong, and how can I fix what I've done to make the code function properly? Or maybe there is an easier way that I haven't discovered yet...

Thanks!

Here is my XML activity code:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_from"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/string_from"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_to"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/string_to"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.appname;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class NumberActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editTextFrom;
    private EditText editTextTo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number);
        editTextFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_from);
        editTextTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_to);
        editTextFrom.setText(editTextFrom.getEditableText());
        editTextTo.setText(editTextTo.getEditableText());
        final int fromValue = 0;
        editTextFrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // What do I put here?
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // What do I put here?
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editTextFrom.setText(fromValue);
            }
        });
        final int toValue = 0;
        editTextTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // What do I put here?
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // What do I put here?
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editTextFrom.setText(toValue);
            }
        });
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(fromValue, toValue);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. *What on Earth am I doing wrong* ... we cant tell you. Because you didn't tell us anything in which ways your code shows unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to generate a random number between a certain range. You have a button, which when clicked, you need that random number to be generated. So what does that mean? It means you don't need to add `editText.addTextChangedListener` to listen continuously for the text changes.

Step 1. Create a method called generateRandomNumber.

```
private int generateRandomNumberBetweenRange(int from, int to){
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(fromValue, toValue);
}
```

Step 2: Set onClickListener to the button that you have in your XML, and in the onClick of this button, get the values from `EditText` and pass those values to the function created in step 1.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              int fromValue = Integer.parseInt(fromValueEditText.getText().toString());
              int toValue = Integer.parseInt(toValueEditText.getText().toString());
              int randomNumber = generateRandomNumberBetweenRange(fromValue, toValue);
              //Your random Number is generated, you can now do whatever you want with it.
              }
          });
```

Comment: Thanks @Vedprakash - this solved my immediate problem. However, what if I wanted to access the `int randomNumber` from a completely different Activity? I'm trying to do that now and I'm getting those "Cannot resolve symbol" errors. I think it has something to do with it being `public void` (void)...

Comment: You'll be able to pass data between activities using Intent.

Comment: But when I click the Generate button after inputting numbers (I used 1 and 12, respectively), the app crashes and says it unfortunately stopped. Maybe I didn't follow your code correctly - I replaced `int from, int to` with `int fromValue, int toValue` and `fromValueEditText` to `editTextFrom` (the ID of my specific EditText). (`fromValueEditText` was throwing an error so I thought that's what I had to do)

Comment: I did not understand a single thing you said.

Comment: Ok, sorry. So basically, I want to output the random number in another activity ("NumberOutputActivity"). In my original activity ("NumberActivity"), I have a big "Generate" button that, when the user clicks on it, should create a random number (within the user-specified range) and take the user to "NumberOutputActivity" where a textbox shows the user their random number. I tried using an Intent but I think I must have done something wrong along the way.

Comment: Android XML for original NumberActivity: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyaadazad/Rxndym/59cbcdc105f055d38ecf22a9d28559d968064d4d/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_number.xml

Comment: Java code for original NumberActivity https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyaadazad/Rxndym/c619b8f22910a11a7c768c75edbb7b0c5841953b/app/src/main/java/com/riyaadazad/rxndym/NumberActivity.java

Comment: Java code for the second activity NumberOutputActivity (it's blank currently): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyaadazad/Rxndym/c619b8f22910a11a7c768c75edbb7b0c5841953b/app/src/main/java/com/riyaadazad/rxndym/NumberOutputActivity.java

Comment: Check this out to pass Integer through Intent in Android. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074097/how-to-pass-integer-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: I followed instructions on the link provided but once I tested the app by clicking on the "Generate" button after inputting a range of numbers (i.e. 1, 12), the app still crashed ("Unfortunately, AppName has stopped."). Here is my code for NumberActivity (raw.githubusercontent.com/riyaadazad/Rxndym/9d71e39f63293ba0bc37ded072736b34d612855d/app/src/main/java/com/riyaadazad/rxndym/NumberActivity.java) and here is my code for NumberOutputActivity (raw.githubusercontent.com/riyaadazad/Rxndym/9d71e39f63293ba0bc37ded072736b34d612855d/app/src/main/java/com/riyaadazad/rxndym/NumberOutputActivity.java).

Comment: You're trying to use getIntent() method outside the onCreate of Activity. Put that getIntent() code in onCreate() below setContentView()

Comment: I did that for only the NumberOutputActivity and the app still crashed. In the example you linked to, should I have changed "intVariableName" or "intValue"? Thanks.

Comment: You did that for NumberOutputActivity and the crash is happening in that activity itself. Change the code to what I told before, adding the code to getIntent() in onCreate() and it'll work fine.

Comment: Sorry, but are you talking about adding the code to onCreate in the original NumberActivity (I tried that as well as NumberOutputActivity, but when I moved the intent before the randomNumber I generated it threw a bunch of errors - probably because when it's so early in the code the compiler has no idea what randomNumber is?)?

Comment: Java code for NumberOutputActivity: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyaadazad/Rxndym/cd430331425ed199ef8f39606824ca32e60dd097/app/src/main/java/com/riyaadazad/rxndym/NumberOutputActivity.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194499/discussion-between-vedprakash-wagh-and-riyaad-azad).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your problem exactly but it seems you have `fromValue` and `toValue` both set as `final` which means they cannot change after they were both set to 0.  That means your `int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(fromValue, toValue);`  is always attempting to call `nextInt(0,0)` which according to the javadocs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Oops. It's just that when I remove `final` from `fromValue` and `toValue`, the code in `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)` throws an error (the code is `editTextFrom.setText(fromValue);` for that specific public void and the `toValue` is similar). Android Studio says `Variable 'fromValue' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`.

Comment: @Riyaad Azad Perhaps try to make them class variables with `private int toValue;` on the line after `private EditText editTextTo;`

Comment: Tried that and it did not throw an error, which is good. But the app still crashes in the emulator when I click the button that takes me to the activity with the random number stuff (so it's not even loading the screen, even though it was before I added this code). Thanks, though.

Comment: @Riyaad Azad Yeah try Vedprakash's solution, you likely have more errors than just declaring those as `final`.  I just knew that was definitely not correct.